# Push notification in mobile app using angular

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

I am currently working on a mobile app using Cordova,AngularJS, Ionic 3, HTML. I wanted to know that how do we push notifications to users are times. Notifications like anything, any reminder, any scheduled meeting or visit or information like that. How do I push notifications? Also the notifications should be triggered even when the app is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Abhilash you can use FCM notification powered by Google firebase. FCM notification will provide all type of notification that you want like: Schedules, Reminder etc. Push notification is working with device unique token. You can easily find push notification code in Google firebase dashboard. If you didn't find code please let me know i'll provide you this code in IONIC. Thank You.

Comment: I looked into FCM. Just out of curiosity, is there any other way? With no firebase?

Comment: Also edited the question, forgot to mention I was using cordava. Also I was reading the Ionic FCM docs and the usage shows only typescript code :(

Comment: i don't think is there any other way to send notification as better as Firebase FCM. If you only want to chat you can use Socket.io, this will also helpful for simple chat aap.

Comment: for Cordova notification with firebase you can follow this link https://medium.com/@t1tan1um/fcm-integration-for-cordova-hybrid-apps-c679f5fc1988 thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. FCM was exactly the thing I was looking for.